# im using Spring hibernate based web service geting Attempt to get length of null array error in line 195

Tags: android, arrays, spring, hibernate

**my question is why i am getting This Error
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.jav‌​a:63) at com.terms.terms.LoginActivity$3.onFailure(LoginActivity.java‌​:195**

<*http://localhost:8080/Term_Project/config/po/rest/login?userName=Lal&password=jad*>  this is my url for testing my service in postman  its working fine there

```
 public class ProjectManager {
        private static ProjectManager sharedManager = new ProjectManager();
        //objects used for store data in shared preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
        SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = null;

        static public String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
        static public String login = "/Term_Project/config/po/rest/login";

===============================================

**this is main Login class**


     public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        // UI references.
        private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
        private EditText mPasswordView;
        private View mProgressView;
        private View mLoginFormView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            // Set up the login form.

            mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
            mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                        attemptLogin();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
            mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();

                }
            });
            mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
            mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
        }

        /**
         * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
         * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
         * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
         */
        private void attemptLogin1() {
            finish();
            finish();
        }

        private void attemptLogin() {
            // Reset errors.
            mEmailView.setError(null);
            mPasswordView.setError(null);

            // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
            String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
            String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

            email = "ADMIN";
            password = "Admin";

           // email = "SMAHAPATRA";
           // password = "SMAHAPATRA";

            boolean cancel = false;
            View focusView = null;

            // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
                focusView = mPasswordView;
                cancel = true;
            }
            // Check for a valid email address.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                focusView = mEmailView;
                cancel = true;
            }
            /*if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
                mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
                focusView = mEmailView;
                cancel = true;
            }*/

            if (cancel) {
                // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
                // form field with an error.
                focusView.requestFocus();
            } else {
                // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
                // perform the user login attempt.
                showProgress(true);
                try {
                    loginUser(email, password);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void loginUser(String email, final String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            //showProgress(true);
            RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
            requestParams.put("userName", email);
            requestParams.put("password", password);

            String urlRequest = ProjectManager.BASE_URL + ProjectManager.login;
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/text");
            client.addHeader("Accept", "application/text");

            client.get(this.getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(urlRequest), requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    try {
                        showProgress(true);
                        String str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                        Log.d("success login", " statusCode " + statusCode + "  " + str);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "get login: "+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);

                        if (jsonObject.has("userId")) {
                            String userId = jsonObject.getString("userId");
                            if (Integer.parseInt(userId) > 0) {
                                ProjectManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn = false;
                                ProjectManager.UserId = userId;
                                ProjectManager.Username = jsonObject.getString("userName");
                                ProjectManager.empMaster.setEmpCd(jsonObject.getString("empID"));
                                ProjectManager.Password = password;
                                ProjectManager.TotalPOCount = jsonObject.getLong("totalPOCount");

                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_username_password), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_username_password), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    try {
                        showProgress(true);
                        String str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                        Log.d("failure responseBody", " statusCode " + statusCode + "  " + str);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail get login: "+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
            //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
            return email.contains("@");
        }

        private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
            //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
            return password.length() > 4;
        }

        /**
         * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
         */
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
        private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
            // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
            // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
            // the progress spinner.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                        show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                        show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
                // and hide the relevant UI components.
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        private void navigateToDashboard() {
            Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
            //Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
        }

        public void login(String email, String password) {
            JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
            StringEntity entity = null;
            try {
                param.put("username", email);
                param.put("password", password);
                entity = new StringEntity(param.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

            String urlRequest = ProjectManager.BASE_URL + ProjectManager.BASE_URL;
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            client.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            client.post(this.getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(urlRequest), entity, "", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    //Log.d("Async post", urlRequest);
                    //Log.d("Async post params:", params + "");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    try {
                        showProgress(false);
                        String str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                        Log.d("success login", " statusCode " + statusCode + "  " + str);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "get search list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
                        if (jsonObject.has("errorMessages")) {
                            if (jsonObject.getString("errorMessages") != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check Username Or Password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        navigateToDashboard();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    try {
                        showProgress(false);
                        String str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                        Log.d("failure responseBody", " statusCode " + statusCode + "  " + str);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }}
```

in project manager class  i create my base url or other url for getting data

not this my Log file

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-19 02:02:35.775 4275-4275/com.terms.terms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.terms.terms, PID: 4275
                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                               at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:63)
                                                               at com.terms.terms.LoginActivity$3.onFailure(LoginActivity.java:195)
                                                               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:319)
                                                               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:138)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
  at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:63)
  at com.terms.terms.LoginActivity$3.onFailure(LoginActivity.java:195)

Comment: and your question?

Comment: my question is why i am  getting  This Error                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:63) at com.terms.terms.LoginActivity$3.onFailure(LoginActivity.java:195)